# SQL Pivot and Distinct from new Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table called `ADMIN` that originally looks like this

```
KEY           VALUE
Version1      2019_RQK@2019
Version2      2019_RQK@2020
Version2      2019_RQK@2021
Version2      2019_RQK@2022
Version2      2020_TKA@2020
Version2      2020_TKA@2021
Version2      2020_TKA@2022
Version2      2020_TKA@2023
```

And I am try to change it to look like this

```
VERSION       YEAR1      YEAR2      YEAR3      YEAR4     
2019_RQK      2019       2020       2021       2022
2020_TKA      2020       2021       2022       2023
```

I wrote some SQL in order to get the left and right versions of the `[VALUE]` columns but I dont know how to condense it so that it only shows a `DISTINCT` as for the left side of the `[VALUE]` column. I tried to use distinct but it still brings up the same repeated entries, this is what I've written so far, I dont know if `PIVOT` function would work here I tried a few things it didn't end up correct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT([VALUE], 7) AS VERSION, RIGHT([VALUE], 4) AS YEAR
FROM ADMIN
WHERE [KEY] LIKE '%VERSION%'
```

Just gives me, not sure how to change it in the same query

```
VERSION      YEAR
2019_RQK     2019
2019_RQK     2020
2019_RQK     2021
2019_RQK     2022
2020_TKA     2020
2020_TKA     2021
2020_TKA     2022
2020_TKA     2023
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, yes, you need a PIVOT table to do that. You can learn all about them [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/), which has a pretty straightforward (and quick!) walkthrough to understand why it works magic.

To PIVOT this table, we need to add a column for YEAR1, YEAR2, etc.. so they can be our headers/new columns. I'll do that with a basic `ROW_NUMBER` function. I know this example has 4 maximum new columns per entry, so I'm hardcoding them in, but the link above explains how you can dynamically generate the `IN` statement if you have an unknown number of maximum columns.

<sub>Please note, my test table was created with col1 and col2 because I am lazy. You should swap those for the actual column names.</sub>

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  -- we start with your basic table, as you provided
  SELECT 
    LEFT(col2, 7) AS VERSION, 
    RIGHT(col2, 4) AS YEAR, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by LEFT(col2, 7) order by RIGHT(col2, 4)) as YearNum /* sort these by the proper year, so we don't get of order */
  FROM ADMIN
  WHERE col1 LIKE '%VERSION%'
) versionResults 
PIVOT (
  max([YEAR]) -- grab the year
  for [YearNum] -- this column holds our new column headers
  in ( /* these are the possible YearNum values, now our new column headers */
    [1],
    [2],
    [3],
    [4]
  )
) as pivotResults
```

[Demo here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=851983c90ae3ab131dd5c06d8badcac2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also extract the first 4 chars as the "base year", then subtract the "Year" from the "Base Year" (and add 1) to get an integer value (1-4) and use those as the PIVOT list.

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=21474741ec20ec694c982543c369d7e8)

The reason this is "difficult" is that you have 3 key values stored in 1 column. At least it's fixed width so easy enough to break apart consistently.

If the VALUE column contains differently formatted data, this won't work.

```
CREATE TABLE Admin
( Key1 char(8)
, Val  char(13)
);

INSERT INTO Admin (Key1, Val)
VALUES
  ('Version1','2019_RQK@2019')
, ('Version2','2019_RQK@2020')
, ('Version2','2019_RQK@2021')
, ('Version2','2019_RQK@2022')
, ('Version2','2020_TKA@2020')
, ('Version2','2020_TKA@2021')
, ('Version2','2020_TKA@2022')
, ('Version2','2020_TKA@2023');

WITH Src AS (
SELECT
      Version  = SUBSTRING(Val,1,8)
    , Year     = CAST(SUBSTRING(Val,10,4) as int)
    , YearCt   = CAST(SUBSTRING(Val,10,4) as int) - CAST(SUBSTRING(Val,1,4) as int) + 1
FROM Admin
)
SELECT
      pvt.Version
    , Year1 = pvt.[1]
    , Year2 = pvt.[2]
    , Year3 = pvt.[3]
    , Year4 = pvt.[4]
FROM Src
PIVOT (MAX(Year) FOR YearCt IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) pvt;
```

Comment: Hi five for having essentially the same answer, but your seems to run on some underlying assumptions that the year of the version name, and possible release years, are sequential/a certain number apart. If I change the last data row to ```2020_TKA@2026```, for example, that field is ```null``` in your results when I play with your demo.

Comment: @CoffeeNeedCoffee good catch. I did make that assumption without even realizing I had (I write similar queries in my prod environment dealing with guaranteed sequential values, so I rushed in).

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamical pivoting such as below one would be a better option in terms of picking the currently inserted years with no applying any manipulation to the query while the data change

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = ( SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('[year',[n],']'),',') 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                             (PARTITION BY LEFT([value], 7) ORDER BY [value]) AS [n] 
                        FROM [admin] ) q );
SET  @query = 
 N'SELECT *
     FROM
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT LEFT([value], 7) AS version, RIGHT([value], 4) AS year,
             CONCAT(''year'',ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                             (PARTITION BY LEFT([value], 7) 
                                  ORDER BY RIGHT([value], 4))) AS [n]
        FROM [admin]
       WHERE [key] LIKE ''%VERSION%'' ) q
    PIVOT (
           MAX([year]) FOR [n] IN (' + @cols + N')
          ) p
    ORDER BY [version]';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=717e8cb9421984fd61f59115d84e61c4)</kbd>

*Btw, you might also split the `value` by `@` sign `SUBSTRING([value],1,CHARINDEX('@',[value])-1)` in order to extract `version`, and `SUBSTRING([value],CHARINDEX('@',[value])+1,LEN([value]))` in order to extract `year` columns without specifying  the length values as arguments within the functions as an alternative.*